# Someone please explain to me how to insert this graphic in a tkinter window

Tags: python, numpy, slider, plotly

This is the code that generates the figure, the truth is I do not know much about tkinter so I do not understand how I can do it, if someone helps me I would appreciate it very much
#importamos las librerias
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

```
f_dt = 3 # time domain frequency, cycles / second
A_dt = 2 # breadth in time domain 
t = np.linspace(0, 4.5, 10000)
g_t = A_dt*np.cos(2*np.pi*f_dt*t)+A_dt
g_t = A_dt*np.cos(2*np.pi*f_dt*t)
r = np.cos(-2*np.pi*f_dt*t)
i = np.sin(-2*np.pi*f_dt*t)         
# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()
fig = px.scatter(width=800, height=800)
# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in np.arange(0, 100,1):
    t=np.arange(0, 4.5, 0.001)
    g_t=A_dt*np.cos(step*np.arange(0, 4.5,0.001)*np.pi)+A_dt
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="#00CED1", width=6),
            name=" = " + str(step),
            x= g_t*np.cos(-2*np.pi*f_dt*t),
            y= g_t*np.sin(-2*np.pi*f_dt*t)
        ))
    

# Make 10th trace visible
fig.data[1].visible = True

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: If you don't know much about `tkinter`, why not [read about it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)?

Comment: I already did it, but the truth is that I study civil engineering and I don't know why they give me this subject that is not relevant to my career, however I must pass it so it is difficult for me to study such a wide library when I do not have much time since I have other more important subjects. thanks